# change css on parent of a:active element

Tags: css

Go an LI holding an `<A>` - for the a:active state I want to change the CSS applied to the parent `<LI>` holding it... but I Cant work out the syntax in CSS....? Sure its a simple solution...?

```
<li><a href="#">link</a></li>
li { background-color: yellow; }
li a:active { color: red; }
```

Above makes the link red on mousedown, but how can I also make the background colour of the `<li>` red when `<a>` is in active state?

UPDATE - not possible in CSS. jQuery solution is below:

```
$('li a').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('makeMeYellow');
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted but you can't do it with css (the clues in the name - cascading) there is no parent selector

Comment: Didn't think it was on reflection... will have to do it with jQuery